# Проблемы с авторизацией через Google

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Пытаюсь разобраться с созданием в проекте Django DRF авторизации через google. В console.cloud.google создал соответствующие credentials:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот html код с указанными credentials:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но выдает вот такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почитал в интернете, есть похожие ошибки, пишут что связано с правильным указанием localhost, проверил, у меня все указано вроде бы верно. В чем еще может быть ошибка?